# How come i get my result in the shell but not my export?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was wondering why in the scrapy shell I do get my result back, however when i try impelementing it in a script. It fails and shows null fields. What would you call that? And how is it fixable?

A screenshot of my output:
[image]

The shell:

```
>>> response.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(9) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first()
u'GU17 9AB'
```

Snippet of my code:

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

  name = 'CYRecursive'
  start_urls = [
      'https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/Company/Find?q=a']

  def parse(self, response):

    for company_url in response.xpath('//div[@class="search_result_title"]/a/@href').extract():
      yield scrapy.Request(
          url=response.urljoin(company_url),
          callback=self.parse_details,
      )

  def parse_details(self, response):

    # Looping throught the searchResult block and yielding it

    for i in response.css('div.col-md-6'):
        if not i.css('#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)'):
            continue
        yield {
            'company_name': i.css('#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)::text').get(),
            'address': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
            'location': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3)::text").extract_first(),
            'postal_code': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(9) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
        }
```

The part giving me trouble is:

```
'postal_code': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(9) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
```

Thank you!

Comment: Edit:

This line supposedly gives nulls:                'postal_code': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(9) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),

Comment: If you need to clarify the question, click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56152573/edit) link.

Comment: Could you try to make the code snippet into a [mcve] -- the shortest possible *self-contained* code someone else can run to see the problem themselves, without changes or additions being needed?

Comment: I just calrified the question thank you, also posted complete code!

Comment: If the code given doesn't actually invoke the function that generates the error, and generate output that shows whether the error occurred, it's not *quite* a MCVE.

Comment: Hmm im not sure what you mean? Is this perhaps what you are after?  https://imgur.com/a/mxdNfoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If this is what you wanted to grab. Try the following:

```
  def parse_details(self, response):
    for i in response.css('#content2'):
        yield {
            'company_name': i.css('[itemprop="name"]::text').get(),
            'address': i.css('[itemprop="streetAddress"]::text').extract_first(),
            'location': i.css("[itemprop='addressLocality']::text").extract_first(),
            'postal_code': i.css("[itemprop='postalCode']::text").extract_first(),
        }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to have! I never knew about the "itemprop"  property! Does it have a specific name i can look it up for in the scrapy guides?

Comment: It's all about selector things. They are called attribute selectors.

Comment: Thanks! I will definatly look into it more!